# How to transform elliptic equation and hyperbola equation into standard form?

Tags: equation-solving

The elliptic trajectory equation and hyperbola trajectory equation are generated according to the code, but the final form is not the standard form. How to generate the standard equation form?

The standard forms of elliptic equation and hyperbola equation are:

```
x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == 1

x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1
```

the first one  Elliptical trajectory equation:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
expr = EuclideanDistance[{0, 4}, {x, y}] + 
   EuclideanDistance[{0, -4}, {x, y}] == 10
eq1 = Refine[Simplify[expr], 
   Assumptions -> {x \[Element] Reals, y \[Element] Reals}] // 
  FullSimplify
eq2 = SubtractSides[eq1, FirstCase[List @@ First@eq1, Sqrt[__]]]
eq3 = ApplySides[#^2 &, eq2] // Expand
eq4 = Apply[Subtract, eq3] == 0
eq5 = SubtractSides[eq4, FirstCase[List @@ First@eq4, k_*Sqrt[__]]]
eq6 = ApplySides[#^2 &, eq5] // Simplify
```

the result is:

```
25 x^2 + 9 y^2 == 225
```

The standard equation form is:

```
x^2/5+y^2/25==1
```

the second Hyperbola trajectory equation：

```
Clear["Global`*"]
expr = EuclideanDistance[{0, 2}, {3, 2}] - 
   EuclideanDistance[{0, -2}, {3, 2}] == 
  EuclideanDistance[{0, -2}, {x, y}] - 
   EuclideanDistance[{0, 2}, {x, y}] 
eq1 = Refine[Simplify[expr], 
  Assumptions -> {x \[Element] Reals, y \[Element] Reals}]
eq2 = ApplySides[#^2 &, eq1] // Simplify
eq3 = Fold[SubtractSides, eq2, Cases[List @@ First@eq2, Sqrt[__]]]
eq4 = ApplySides[#^2 &, eq3] // Simplify
```

the result is :

```
3 + x^2 == 3 y^2
```

The standard equation form is:

```
y^2-x^2/3==1
```

The results obtained are not in the form of standard equations. How can we obtain the standard equation?

Comment: Define "standard equation."

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The standard "standard equation" in US math ed has the form of a sum/difference of squares equals the number one. I don't know how standard that terminology is outside the US. Since this is an international site, perhaps, @ csn889, you could edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: Your `ApplySides` statements are determining the final form of the equations.  Why not use `ApplySides` to get the equations the way you want?

Comment: @csn889, you have now posted around 10 different partial questions on the manipulation of ellipse equation, and the last few of them are just concatenating the code from previous answers. Can you please clearly state what is you _overall_ final goal with these conic sections? Are you doing this for educational purposes, and want to show the derivation of the standard form? Do you just want the parameters of the standard form? Note that there are also several questions already about quadratic forms:

Comment: 1. [How to simplify an equation corresponding to an ellipsoid?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/229903/how-to-simplify-an-equation-corresponding-to-an-ellipsoid), 2. [How do I get my equation to have the form $(x−a)^2+(y−b)^2+(z−c)^2−d=0$?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20051/how-do-i-get-my-equation-to-have-the-form-x-a2-y-b2-z-c2-d-0)

Comment: 3. [Convert an expression from one form to another](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/convert-an-expression-from-one-form-to-another), 4. [An easier way to find the properties of an ellipse from its equation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51654/an-easier-way-to-find-the-properties-of-an-ellipse-from-its-equation)

Comment: Please answer the questions in comment to clarify your problem. One more question: do you want `-(x^2/3) + y^2 == 1` or `-(x^2/(Sqrt[3])^2) + y^2/(1)^2 == 1` as the output?

Comment: want to get ```x^2/5+y^2/25==1``` and ```y^2-x^2/3==1```

Comment: What you have posted is not really a _complete_ standard form because it is missing an offset, and I have a strong feeling that when we answer this question, you will open a new one with "How to convert to standard form $(x-x_0)^2/a^2+(y-y_0)^2/b^2=1$?" Also, please address my questions above :)

Comment: ```Clear["Global`*"]
exp = EuclideanDistance[{0, 2}, {x, y}] + 
   EuclideanDistance[{0, -2}, {x, y}] == 10
expr = Refine[exp, 
  Assumptions -> {x \[Element] Reals, y \[Element] Reals}]
eqn = Apply[Subtract, expr] == 0
eq1 = SubtractSides[eqn, FirstCase[List @@ First@eqn, k_.*Sqrt[__]]]
eq2 = ApplySides[#^2 &, eq1] // Expand
eq3 = Apply[Subtract, eq2] == 0
eq4 = SubtractSides[eq3, FirstCase[List @@ First@eq3, k_.*Sqrt[__]]]
eq5 = ApplySides[#^2 &, eq4] // Simplify
```

Comment: add following code the result is wrong!

Comment: ```otherform = a (b + x)^2 + c (d + y)^2 == 1;
sol = SolveAlways[First[eq5] == First[otherform], {x, y}]
otherform /. First[sol]```

Comment: @Domen，The above method did not solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expr1 = EuclideanDistance[{0, 4}, {x, y}] + EuclideanDistance[{0, -4}, {x, y}] == 10;
expr2 = EuclideanDistance[{0, 2}, {3, 2}] - EuclideanDistance[{0, -2}, {3, 2}] == 
   EuclideanDistance[{0, -2}, {x, y}] - EuclideanDistance[{0, 2}, {x, y}];
```

```
expr1

Refine[%, Assumptions -> {x, y} ∈ Reals]

% /. s1_Sqrt[__] + s2_Sqrt[__] == a_ :> s1 == a - s2

ApplySides[#^2 &, %] // Expand

SubtractSides[%]

% /. a_ + (s : _.*Sqrt[__]) == 0 :> a == -s

ApplySides[#^2 &, %] // Simplify

SubtractSides[%]

% /. (a_?NumberQ + b_ == 0) :> b == -a

DivideSides[%] // Expand
```

$$\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{25}=1$$

```
expr2

(* ... same code as above ... *)
```

$$-\frac{x^2}{3}+y^2=1$$

Answer (score 0):

[How to optimize the code for deriving the standard equation of the Apollonian circle?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284016/how-to-optimize-the-code-for-deriving-the-standard-equation-of-the-apollonian-ci)

Based on xzczd's solution therein:

```
ClearAll["`*"]
eq = 25 x^2 - 9 y^2 == 225
Apply[Subtract]@eq
rule = Solve[
   ForAll[{x, y}, 
    Apply[Subtract]@eq == 
     dd ((x - aa)^2/ff + (y - bb)^2/gg - 1)], {aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff,
     gg}][[1]]
(x - aa)^2/ff + (y - bb)^2/gg == 1 /. rule
```